# Passing special character in DT Table

Tags: r

I am trying to escape special character "--" in column of DT table but formatPercentage is not letting this happen , manually passing formatPercentage(c(2,3,5)) is working and i want to make it dynamic. so i am looking for a solution through which column having "--" can be displayed in DT table.

I have tried ifelse but doesn't work , this code is just a part of my function.

```
df <- mtcars[1:6,1:5]
df$drat <- "--"
df$disp <- "--"

datatable(df, escape = FALSE) %>% 
  formatPercentage(2:5)
```

so the actual problem is I am trying to mask one column in my DT table output but formatPercentage not providing the require output. so i am looking for a solution .

My function is big thats why i am unable to create a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the columns which has `'--'` in them.

```
library(DT)

all_cols <- 2:5
format_cols <- setdiff(all_cols, which(colSums(df == '--') > 0))

datatable(df, escape = FALSE) %>% formatPercentage(format_cols)
```

[image]

Comment: this is working perfectly but if any column have NA in the rows then it converting to Blanks in the output . but i required if there is any NA in any column  then it should NA in the DT table as well.

Comment: You may turn them to string `NA`. `df[is.na(df)] <- "NA"`

Comment: I converted it into string then still the output is coming as blank columns

Comment: You can ask that as a new question then.